# PHP, скрипт который жрет лишние ресурсы

Tags: php, оптимизация, codeigniter, производительность

Ребята, мне нужна помощь в оптимизации скрипта сайта. Данный скрипт является авто-загружаемой либой в CodeIgniter, т.е. это основной скрипт который выполняется на каждой странице сайта.
Мне не нравится как этот скрипт работает, где-то я накосячил, особенно в определении языкового предпочтения юзера, ну и в общем, тоже всё плохо. Помогите правильно все сделать чтобы его прожорливость стала меньше.

```
public $dbh,  //соединение
       $metaTags = array('meta_t'=>NULL,'meta_d'=>NULL,'meta_k'=>NULL),
       $langs = array(
            'ru' => array('ru','be','uk','kk','ka','lt','lv','et','mo','az','tg','uz','tk'),    //русский
            'de' => array('de','sl','hu','rm','nl'),                                            //немецкий
            'fr' => array('fr','lb','bi','cm','br'),                                            //французкий
            'sv' => array('sv','fi'),                                                           //шведский
            'zh' => 'zh',                                                                       //китайский
            'es' => array('es','gn','qu','ay'),                                                 //испанский
            'it' => array('it','la','sc','sl'),                                                 //итальянский
            'pl' => array('pl','cs','sk','ro'),                                                 //польский
            'pt' => 'pt',                                                                       //португальский
            'da' => array('da','fo')                                                            //датский
        ),  

        $langs_text = array(
            'en' => 'English',
            'ru' => 'Русский',
            'de' => 'Deutsch', 
            'fr' => 'Français', 
            'sv' => 'Svenska',  
            'zh' => '中國', 
            'es' => 'Español',  
            'it' => 'Italiano',  
            'pl' => 'Polski', 
            'pt' => 'Português',
            'da' => 'Dansk'
        );

function __construct() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    define('MODULE_DIR',APPPATH.'views/modules/');   //корневой каталог модулей
    define('ROOTCDIR', 'd/');
    define('TMP_DIR', 'd/tmp/');
    define('CHACHEDIR', 'd/c/');
    define('ROOTFILESDIR', '../f/');
    define('HOST', $CI->config->base_url(''));      
    define('DBNAME', 'test-db');
                                                //извлечение первого параметр урла - предполож языковой индекс
    $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".DBNAME,'test','1111',
                            array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));

    /***
    * проверка параметра обновления сессии
    ****/
    if(!empty($_SESSION['ID'])){
        $q = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `usr` WHERE `id`=? AND `r`=?");
        $q->execute(array(xss($_SESSION['ID']),1));
        if($q->fetchColumn()>0){
            //exit('x');
            $q = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE `usr` SET `r`=? WHERE `id`=?");
            $q->execute(array(0,xss($_SESSION['ID'])));
            $_SESSION = NULL;
            session_destroy();
        }
    }

    require_once APPPATH.'libraries/db.php';    // библиотека для работы с БД 

    $id = NULL;  //ид юзера
    $login = NULL;  //логин
    $lvl = NULL;  //ост данные
    $avatar = NULL;
    $prp = NULL;
    $prm = NULL;
    $cmtp = NULL;
    $cmtm = NULL;
    $reg = NULL;
    $first_name = NULL;
    $last_name = NULL;
    $sex = NULL;
    $format = FALSE;
    $mobile = FALSE;

    if (isset($_SESSION['FORMAT'])) { //если авторизация была
        $id = $_SESSION['ID'];
        $login = $_SESSION['LOGIN'];
        $lvl = $_SESSION['LVL'];
        $reg = $_SESSION['R'];
        $avatar = $_SESSION['AVATAR'];
        $prp = $_SESSION['PRP'];
        $prm = $_SESSION['PRM'];
        $cmtp = $_SESSION['CMTP'];
        $cmtm = $_SESSION['CMTM'];
        $sex = $_SESSION['SEX'];
        $first_name = $_SESSION['F_NAME'];
        $last_name = $_SESSION['L_NAME'];
        $format = $_SESSION['FORMAT'];
        $mobile = $_SESSION['MOBILE'];
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['R']) && !empty($_COOKIE['HS']) && !empty($_COOKIE['ID']) ){
        $q = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `usr` WHERE `id`=? AND `hs`=?");
        $q->execute(array(xss($_COOKIE['ID']),xss($_COOKIE['HS'])));
        if($q->fetchColumn()>0){
            $q = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`,`login`,`lvl`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`sex`,`opt_avatar`,`op`,`om`,`opp`,`opm` FROM `usr` WHERE `id`=? AND `hs`=?");
            $q->execute(array(xss($_COOKIE['ID']),xss($_COOKIE['HS'])));
            $r = $q->fetch();
            $id = $r['id'];
            $login = $r['login'];
            $lvl = $r['LVL'];
            $sex = $r['sex'];
            $avatar = $r['opt_avatar'];
            $reg = TRUE;
            $first_name = $r['first_name'];
            $last_name = $r['last_name'];
            $prp = $r['op'];
            $prm = $r['om'];
            $cmtp = $r['opp'];
            $cmtm = $r['opm'];
        }
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['MOBILE']) ){
        $userData = $this->getUserData();
        $format = FALSE;
        $mobile = 0;
        if($userData['mobile']){
            $mobile = 1;
        }
        if($userData['android']){
            $mobile = 1;
            if((int)$userData['android_version']>=4){
                $format = TRUE;
            }
        }
        if($userData['browser']=='chrome' || $userData['browser']=='opera'){
            $format = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if(empty($_SESSION['LANG'])){   //если нет в сессии языка то присвоим его по AccepLng
        $lang = $this->setHL($CI);
        $_SESSION['LANG'] = $lang;
    }else {
        $lang = $_SESSION['LANG'];
    }

    $_SESSION['LANG'] = $lang;
    $_SESSION['FORMAT'] = $format;
    $_SESSION['MOBILE'] = $mobile;
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $id;
    $_SESSION['LOGIN'] = $login;
    $_SESSION['LVL'] = $lvl;
    $_SESSION['R'] = $reg;
    $_SESSION['AVATAR'] = $avatar;
    $_SESSION['F_NAME'] = $first_name;
    $_SESSION['L_NAME'] = $last_name;
    $_SESSION['SEX'] = $sex;
    $_SESSION['PRP'] = $prp;
    $_SESSION['PRM'] = $prm;
    $_SESSION['CMTP'] = $cmtp;
    $_SESSION['CMTM'] = $cmtm;

    define('LANG',$lang);
    define('ID',$id);
    define('LOGIN', $login);
    define('lvl', $lvl);
    define('REG', $reg);
    define('F_NAME', $first_name);
    define('L_NAME', $last_name);
    define('AVATAR', $avatar);
    define('PRP', $prp);
    define('PRM', $prm);
    define('CMTP', $cmtp);
    define('CMTM', $cmtm);
    define('SEX', $sex);
    define('FORMAT', $format);
    define('MOBILE', $mobile);
    define('C_LINES', 50);
    define('LM_SEC', 51);
    define('LM_EL', 52);
    define('DATE_FORMAT', "Y-m-d G:i:s");
    define('SUPPORT_MAIL', 'support@test.com');

    /***
    ***если зареганный то обновим последнее посещение
    ***/

    if(REG){
            $q = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE `usr` SET `last_visit`=? WHERE `id`=?");
            $q->execute(array(date(DATE_FORMAT),ID));            
            define('NOTIFY', $this->getCountNotify());
    }else{
            define('NOTIFY',FALSE);
    }
}

public function getCountNotify() {
    $q = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ntf` WHERE `u_id`=?");
    $q->execute(array(ID));
    return $q->fetchColumn();
}

public function setHL($CI) {                                //получает язык юзера
    $CI->load->library('lang_detect');
    $lang = $CI->lang_detect->getBestMatch('en', $this->langs);
    return $lang;
}

private function getUserData() {
    if(preg_match('/Opera Mini/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){$browser='opera_mini';}
    else if(preg_match('/Opera/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){$browser='opera';}
    else if(preg_match('/Firefox/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){$browser='mozilla';}
    else if(preg_match('/Chrome/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){$browser='chrome';}
    else if(preg_match('/(MSIE)|(rv)/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){$browser='msie';}
    else if(preg_match('/AppleWebKit/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){$browser='safari';}
    else{$browser='chrome';}
    $data['browser'] = $browser;
    require_once APPPATH.'libraries/mobile_detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
    $data['android']=$detect->isAndroidOS();
    $data['android_version']=$detect->version('Android');
    if($detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet()){
        $data['mobile'] = TRUE;
    }else{
         $data['mobile'] = FALSE;
    }
    return $data;
}

//to do more actions....
```

Comment: "Мне не нравится как этот скрипт работает, где-то я накосячил, особенно в определении языкового предпочтения юзера, ну и в общем, тоже всё плохо" - понятность задачи 0%.

Comment: для начала разберитесь, как работает профайлер, потом посмотрите на результаты. Возможно, указанный скрипт потребляет менее процента от общей нагрузки и Ваши страхи безосновательны.

Comment: Ужасный скрипт-код.

Comment: посмотрите расширение INTL http://php.net/manual/ru/book.intl.php